# How do I get my JTextArea to look neat and have a fixed size?

Tags: java, arrays, string, formatting, 2d

So I have a game which involves progressing around a map, represented by a 2D Array. The array of the map is an int[15][10], and currently has only these objects on it:

```
public void createStart(){

    //Creates a Building
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        theMap[0][i] = 3;
        theMap[1][i] = 3;
    }
    //Creates a door in the building
    theMap[1][1] = 2;


}
```

So it would be like theMap.createStart(); To then draw the map on the JTextArea I override the string method:

```
//Prints the Map
//1 = o, representing the hero
//2 = e, representing an entrance
//3 = x, representing building / wall
//4 = p, representing a person
public String toString(){
    String spacing = "     ";
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            if(theMap[i][j] == 0){
                result +=(spacing + "");
            }
            if(theMap[i][j] == 3){
                result +=(spacing + "X");
            }
            if(theMap[i][j] == 1){
                result +=(spacing + "o");
            }
            if(theMap[i][j] == 2){
                result +=("    " + "E");
            }
            if(theMap[i][j] == 4){
                result +=(spacing + "e");
            }
        }
        result += "\n"; //Newline at end of row
    }
    return result;
}
```

The spacing just gives it a nice space between each object, making it easier to see. But the problem is that characters such as x, o and e have different sizes, and so they make the text look unaligned when it prints to a map. You can see it in my example here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN5l5.jpg

The second line is slightly off compared to the top line.

I'm just wondering if there's any formatting tricks I can use to align all of this correctly, or if  there is another solution to this problem. I'm not great at coding so this is a pretty basic construct for a map, but I'm pretty happy with it so far.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your map is just off, are you certain your map is set up correctly?? Sorry, you're using "" in one place but an actual letter everywhere else. Have you tried " "(space)

Comment: It works fine when all the characters are the same, the "" is used in the result string, just an empty string that I can add to in order to print out everything.

Comment: Sorry, I meant this section right here:

     result +=(spacing + "");

Have you tried puting a "(space)" there instead of ""?

Comment: Oh gotcha. Just tried adding it, but didn't fix the look of it.